# MAX7219 with 8digit 7seg array

Tags: max7219

I have a concern about the library port handling. I have used direct port direction manipulation successfully in previous projects but there seems to be a problem here.

```cpp
// This code mostly taken from the example
#include "LedControl.h"

LedControl lc=LedControl(11,13,10,1);
//LedControl lc=LedControl(12,11,10,1); // original
// pin 12 is connected to the DIN pin (now MOSI 11)
// pin 11 is connected to the CLK pin (now SCK 13)
// pin 10 is connected to the CS pin  (now SS 10)
// 1 as we are only using 1 MAX7219

// I am actually using all arduino pins except 12 for my project
#define PD_MSK  B11111100 // Data pins PD2..7 (pins2..7)
#define PB_MSK  B00000011 // Data pins PB0,1 (pins8,9)
#define PC_MSK  B00001111 // Data pins PC0..3 (pins 14..17)

void setup()
{
// set pins 2..9 as inputs  
  DDRD = DDRD & !PD_MSK; // this works OK
  DDRB = DDRB & !PB_MSK; // configure ports D,B inputs *** doesnt work with this
 // pinMode(8, INPUT); //*** does work with this
  //pinMode(9, INPUT); //*** does work with this

  DDRC = DDRC | PC_MSK; // configure PortC0..3 as outputs
  PORTC |= 0x0F; // set PortC0..3 high (default)

  // the zero refers to the MAX7219 number, it is zero for 1 chip
  lc.shutdown(0,false);// turn off power saving, enables display
  lc.setIntensity(0,8);// sets brightness (0~15 possible values)
  lc.clearDisplay(0);// clear screen

}
void loop()
{
  //numbers 7 to 0
  for (int a=0; a<8; a++)
  {
    lc.setDigit(0,a,a,false);
  }

  delay(1000);

  //display number 8 on all segments
  for (int a=0; a<8; a++)
  {
    lc.setDigit(0,a,8,false);
  }
  delay(1000);

  // numbers 7 to 0 reverse order
  for (int a=8; a>=0; a--)
  {
    lc.setDigit(0,a,a,false);
    //delay(100);
  }
  delay(1000);

}
```

The direct port direction setting does not seem to allow the library to work while the pinMode commands doing the same job do. I note that the library uses software SPI but I would like to use hardware if possible. I have certainly used hardware SPI with frequent port direction changes on the remaining pins for other projects.
Any insight as to why this problem occurs?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the connection between "the library does not work if I setup ports manually" and "I would like to use hardware SPI"?

Comment: Since most libraries come as Open Source, did you peek into its sources? Is this one open? If so, what did your research reveal?

Comment: The ! is a logic operator. Bitwise variant is ~

Comment: However after the start/restart DDRx are cleared and configured as inputs, so I don't see any point in those `&=`

Comment: What tells "LedControl.h" that you are using hardware SPI vs software SPI?

Answer (score -1):

As always I recommend the old RTFM (read the f***ing manual) of the [LedControl.h library](http://wayoda.github.io/LedControl/pages/software).
In the FAQ its clearly stated:

> Why don't you use the hardware SPI-Bus of the Arduino?
>
> When I wrote the first version of the library I didn't knew much about
>   the Arduino or AVR processors in general and I knew nothing about
>   writing code for the hardware SPI-bus on an ATMega. But I knew how the
>   SPI protocol works and how I could make this work using simple
>   digitalWrite() commands. I turned out the library code is fast enough
>   for common use cases, so there is no need for doing Hi-Speed
>   communications.
>
> Other strong points in favour of the (admittedly trivial) code design
>   are - Use any three free IO-Pins of your board for the hardware -
>   Simple to debug. Much easier than managing 3 differnt SPI devices
>   connected to the same hardware bus - Library is easily portable to
>   other platforms, since it uses only two very basic functions from the
>   Arduino language

So with this library you clearly have never used hardware SPI (although you could use the pins, but only via softwareSPI)

Comment: Answer #2 pointed out that I had used the wrong operator to set the port direction. (! instead of ~ - bitwise.) My mistake! I want to use hardware SPI in my eventual project (this was just a test) as it can be faster. I used this library to ensure that the external hardware worked -it does now. Using different pins has no benefit in my case so I will probably write my own (hardware) SPI driver. I already have a port direction control system to create a 8bit IO bus for use with other external hardware - if I copy it correctly this time. Thanks to all who took time and found my error.